# Validate JSON Request with Respect/Validation

Tags: php, slim, respect-validation

I have a JSON request which exactly follow the rules, but the result keeps failing.
Let's say I have a request like this:

```
{
"name"  :   "Angela White",
"dateOfBirth" : "01/01/98"
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {
    
    public function register($request, $response) {
        $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
        
        $name = trim($parsedBody['name']);
        $dateOfBirth = $parsedBody['dateOfBirth'];
        
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->setName($name);
        $customer->setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth);
        
        $rules = $customer->customerValidator();

        $data = array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'dateOfBirth'  => $dateOfBirth,
        );

        
        foreach($data as $key => $val) {
            try{
                $rules->check($val);
            } catch(\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $errors = $e->getMessage();
                return $response->withJson($errors, 401);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is class to validate the data:

```
class Customer {
    private $name;
    private $dateOfBirth;
    
    public function setName($input) {
        $this->name = $input;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setDateOfBirth($input) {
        $this->dateOfBirth = $input;
    }

    public function getDateOfBirth() {
        return $this->dateOfBirth;
    }

    
    public function customerValidator() {
        
        return v::attribute($this->getName(), v::stringType()->length(2, null)->setName('Name'))
            ->attribute('dateOfBirth', v::notEmpty()->date('d/m/y')->setName('Date of birth'));

    }


}
```

And as the result I got this:

```
{
    "API_Response": {
        "Status": {
            "Message": "Attribute Name must be present",
            "_ErrorCode": 401,
            "_TimeStamp": 1647247097
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the result is success but why is the message still "Attribute Name must be present" ?
Does anyone can help me, what have I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: Can it just be a problem of case sensitive? You define the `setName('Name')` with capital *N* but your json has "name" with lowercase *n*

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. It would be shown in error message. If I change Name into name, the error message would be  "Attribute name must be present"

Comment: Hi @aew09. Which version of respect/validation are you using?

Comment: Hi @DavidePastore I'm using respect/validation v2.2

Answer (score 0):

There are different issues.

### 1. Usage of the attribute validator

The one that's inside the `customerValidator` function. Here you are using the [attribute rule](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/Attribute/#attribute) that accepts the name of the attribute and not its value. Replacing `$this->getName()` with `'name'` should be enough:

```
class Customer {
  private $name;
  private $dateOfBirth;

  public function setName($input) {
    $this->name = $input;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function setDateOfBirth($input) {
    $this->dateOfBirth = $input;
  }

  public function getDateOfBirth() {
    return $this->dateOfBirth;
  }

  public function customerValidator() {
    return v::attribute('name', v::stringType()->length(2, null)->setName('Name'))
        ->attribute('dateOfBirth', v::notEmpty()->date('d/m/y')->setName('Date of birth'));

  }

}
```

### 2. Validation check in the controller

You already have the object with all the properties set, so it's better to validate it, instead of iterating over all the keys you defined.

```
class RegisterController extends Controller {
    
    public function register($request, $response) {
        $parsedBody = $request->getParsedBody();
        
        $name = trim($parsedBody['name']);
        $dateOfBirth = $parsedBody['dateOfBirth'];
        
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->setName($name);
        $customer->setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth);
        
        $rules = $customer->customerValidator();

        $data = array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'dateOfBirth'  => $dateOfBirth,
        );

        try{
            $rules->check($customer);
        } catch(\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            $errors = $e->getMessage();
            return $response->withJson($errors, 401);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh you're right, for no.1 I just wanna try how if I replace 'name' with $this->getName(). For no.2  it works for me. Thanks!